# SharePoint Online : Search webpart category missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, search-results

**Search** webpart category is missing in SharePoint Online WebPart page (E3 Plan)

I am trying to create Search Result, Search Box and Refiners webparts in Webpart page.

I am added into Designer security group of the site as well.

[image: screenshot from my environment]

Help me to get it displayed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be the reason that custom scripts are disabled on root site collection for security reasons and due to that Script Editor, Content Editor web part and many other web parts or features are not available where user can add custom scripts. Follow the below links to active the custom script.

Please refer below link:

[Missing web part and features in office 365](https://mstechtalk.com/missing-web-part-features-office-365/).

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati